# Amount of Sqlite operation block the UI in Android Asynchronous Http Client onSuccess()

Tags: android, sqlite, http, asynchronous, block

```java
@Override
public void onStart() {
    setCharset("GB2312");
    progess_bar_PopupWindow();
}

@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    String[] split_array = JwcRegex
            .parse_department_list(response);
    Sql.dep_update(split_array);//here contain amount of sql insert operation
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello rex",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (pw_progress_window.isShowing()) {
        pw_progress_window.dismiss();
    }
}
```

When the http request start, `progess_bar_PopupWindow()` show the popwindow which has a progressbar, but the progress bar is stilling, after the request it closed in my onSuccess(). but removed the `Sql.dep_update(split_array)`, the progress bar works well. how to deal?

Comment: what is in the dep_update operation? your code doesn't reach the "if" when you call dep_update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. As follows:

1. add synchronized with query and exec method in Sql class.
   Some error caused by concurrent read/write sqlite. The synchronized keyword could synchronized the operation
2. put popwindow(with my progressbar in it) showing method `showAtLocation()` in `onWindowFocusChanged()` method.
3. put the method which has amount of operation in a new thread. code as follow:

```java
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!hasLoad) {
        get_departments();
        hasLoad = true;
    }
}
```

```java
public void exec(String sql) {
    synchronized (this) {
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
```

```java
@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
    Yangtzeu.TempString = JwcRegex
        .parse_department_list(response);

    if (pw_progress_window.isShowing()) {
        pw_progress_window.dismiss();
    }

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JwcDB.dep_update(Yangtzeu.TempString);
            ComDB.kv_set("dep_list_exp", "false");
        }
    }).start();
}
```